# How to speed up R code

Tags: r, loops, tm

The code below works fine to remove the stopwords in myCharVector. But when the myCharVector has large number of sentences, it takes too long time to complete. How to speed up the loop operation (using apply)?

Thanks.

```
library(tm)

myCharVector  <- c("This is the first sentence", "hello this is second", "and now is the third one")
for(i in 1:length(myCharVector))  
{
for(j in 1:length(stopwords("en")))
{
tmp1 <- paste(stopwords("en")[j], " ", sep = "")
tmp1 <- paste(" ", tmp1, sep = "")
myCharVector[i] <- gsub(tmp1,  " ", myCharVector[i]) 
}  
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `tm_map` and `removeWords`?

Comment: @Henrik I tried with `rm_stopwords(myCharVector, tm::stopwords("en"))`, but this removes `This`, and `and` while the expected output based on the loop have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try `mgsub`

```
library(qdap)
 mgsub(sprintf(' %s ', stopwords('en')), ' ', myCharVector)
#[1] "This first sentence" "hello second"        "and now third one"
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that in this case there’s a [domain-specific solution](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/qdap/docs/rm_stopwords).

In general, though, strive to make more use of R’s vectorised operations. For instance, instead of `paste`ing every word separately, you can do this:

```
stopwords = paste0(' ', stopwords('en'), ' ')
```

This surrounds every stopword in turn by spaces. In the same vein, you don’t need to loop over `myCharVector`, you can use `gsub` directly.

And most importantly, **do not loop over indices**. This is indirect, slow and (almost?) always unnecessary. Loop over the entries directly instead:

```
for (word in paste0(' ', stopwords('en'), ' '))
    myCharVector = gsub(word, ' ', myCharVector)
```

This is at the same time much shorter, clearer and more efficient than your solution.

(That said, this will yield the wrong result anyway, you should really use the predefined function.)